# Debugging in ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, debugging, rdebug

What do you guys use for debugging in ruby 1.9? rdebug doesn't seem to be compatible.. is there anything out there?

Comment: Ignore the first answer; `ruby-debug19` is out of date now.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Note: this answer was correct but is now out of date. See the below correct answer. TL;DR: use 'debugger' now.**

ruby-debug is now available with Ruby 1.9.x. See http://www.github.com/mark-moseley

To install (using gem on 1.9 Ruby installation):

```
gem install ruby-debug19
```

(with perhaps the necessary 'sudo' in front of it).

Comment: I made a cursory attempt and it didn't work. Need some more time to look at this.

Comment: ruby-debug-ide is working now - you can get the new gem at http://cloud.github.com/downloads/mark-moseley/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.7.gem

Comment: nice work :) but could you make a fatgem (containing both 1.8 and 1.9 ruby-debug versions) so we dont have to remember to do rubydebbug19 ? :)

Comment: It doesn't seem fair to downvote this just because the passage of time has made it now the wrong answer.  SO needs some way of handling such use cases, to allow the *new* right answer to become the first listed, without penalizing authors of older answers that are not useful to anyone anymore.

Answer (score 167):

**`ruby-debug19` is not maintained anymore. All the other answers are outdated.**

But there's an alternative:

**[`debugger`](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) to the rescue!**

Put this in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

**It just works.** - And it is included in the rails Gemfile since 3.2.something to replace `ruby-debug19`. It has the exact same functionality and is actively maintained.

Comment: Works nicely. Much better than installing ruby-debug by hand. Thanks.

Comment: This really needs to be moved up as the top answer.

Comment: Yes, really this answer must be the top answer.

Comment: And how about where this actually goes in the Gemfile.

Comment: Does not matter. Put it wherever you like, just not inside a group block (Not in `group :development do ... end` or the like), because it already contains a group.

Comment: I did that, but I still get the message "You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug'". debugger is installed and in gem. any suggestions?

Comment: This works! Verified with Ruby 1.9.1 by adding `gem 'debugger'` to the `Gemfile`.

Comment: Works with RailsInstaller 2.1.0 (ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]) on Win XP. Thanks!

Comment: Can I use with IDE? How?

Answer (score 70):

**UPDATE FOR RUBY 2.0+ and FOLLOWING**

[byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) is the currently recommended debugger for Ruby 2.0+

This issue has been [documented here](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/125#issuecomment-43353446), and cldwalker, the author of debugger, notes that debugger will be scoped to Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3.

**UPDATE 2**

It is true that ruby-debug is not actively maintained even if I can't find anywhere that is not maintained any longer.

You can use the [new debugger gem](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) if you need a help to start with the new gem you can see [Ryan Bates rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-ruby-revised).

In your Gemfile put:

```
gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

You can then add a breakpoint anywhere in your code using the `debugger` keyword.

**YOU CAN STILL USE**

linecache19 and ruby-debug-base19 with:

bash < <(curl -L https://raw.github.com/gist/1333785)

OLD ANSWERS

Just an add on about this with rvm, ruby 1.9.1-p378.
True story is that even if ruby-debug is 1.9.x ready, linecache-0.43 is not.
The solution is to install:

```
gem install ruby-debug19
```

This solves the problem for me.

**OLD UPDATE**

If you are having problems with ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3 debugging putting:

```
gem 'ruby-debug-base19', "0.11.24"
gem 'ruby-debug19', "0.11.6"
```

In your Gemfile and doing a

```
bundle install
```

Will make you a happy debugger again.

Comment: Thanks, to me that was the more appropriate answer. But maybe this is because you replied almost a year later and things changed for good in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

Some things you could try

1) run it with ruby’s normal debugger -rdebug [1] kind of slow

2) run it with unroller gem [kind of stinks, way slow]

3) use a lot of print statements  fast, kind of less introspection possible

4) drop to an irb prompt and run some code from there.

you could list the code by creating your own “drop to irb prompt” that listed the code around itself [use caller to discover where you where] then drop to a normal irb prompt.

5) maybe jruby in 1.9 compat mode has a debugger?

[1] http://beaver.net/rdebug/index-0.html

Answer (score 3):

If you still have a problem after installing ruby-debug19 try updating ruby-debug-base19. I had errors and couldn't run WEBrick in debug mode until I did that.

```
gem update ruby-debug-base19
```

Oh, and thanks Mr. Moseley for all your hard work!

Answer (score 2):

See my answer here :
[Ruby-debug not working - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9260206/889617)

It's about getting Ruby debugging to work with the following setup

- Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2
- Aptana Studio 3 (Build 3.0.8.201201201658)
- Using rvm, in my project working directory I have a .rvmrc stating:

  ```
  rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p0@mygemset
  ```

I hope this helps!

-- Freddy

Answer (score 2):

I used following and it works great for me:

gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is a good IDE for RoR. Good debugger too.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe the debugger works for Ruby 1.9.1 (C implementation) yet. At least, I have not been successful in getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The ruby 1.9.1-p243 version is out and compitable ruby-debug-ide is also working properly. Install ruby-debug-ide using the following command:

> gem install ruby-debug-ide

This will install the ruby-debug-base19 and ruby-debug-ide gems. But before this make sure you install the mingw successfully by following the Development kit docs available from [RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167).

Answer (score 0):

Latest features are available in ruby-debug-ide19 gem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of choices, depending on your needs.

I use [pry-moves](https://github.com/garmoshka-mo/pry-moves) because I can "look back" into what happened inside of previous command by re-executing them in debug mode right from the place.

Answer (score -1):

doesn't anyone use:
ruby -rdebug script.rb

then you can use:
b script.rb:## (where ## is the line number of a valid ruby command) otherwise you are going to maybe be in the middle of rubygems or one of your required chunks of code.

Then you can simply set the next breakpoint as b:##