# ruby debug with windows8 and aptana

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-8

I have installed

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide --pre
```

but when i run debug I got this error message

```
4088: Exception in DebugThread loop: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Backtrace:
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.2.2/lib/ruby-debug/interface.rb:163:in `read_command'
  from: c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:83:in `process_commands'
  from: c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:160:in `block in start_control'
Exiting
```

not sure what is missing ?

**UPDATE:**

I installed this gem

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide19 --platform=ruby
```

and removed

```
gem 'debugger'
```

in my Gemfile based on this post 
[Can't run RubyMine debugger with RVM, Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331920/cant-run-rubymine-debugger-with-rvm-ruby-1-9-2-and-rails-3)

It works now!

Answer (score 2):

After several *days* of experimenting, I finally had success with Aptana 3.2.2 in Windows 8 using a combination of steps discovered from other posts.  It seems that the steps one person follows to success doesn't work for many others, but in case it might help, below are the steps I took.  I am new to Ruby and Rails, so at the risk of including steps which are not relevant, I will try to be very detailed.  Note that I had already installed MySQL and had it working with an installation of Ruby 1.9.3.

1. Wiped out existing Ruby and DevKit installations (including in the Windows registry).  (I renamed my C:\Ruby193 directory to C:\Ruby193_old.  See step 8d below.)
2. Installed Ruby using rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p327.exe from the rubyinstaller.org web site.  I installed it to C:\Ruby193.
3. Installed the DevKit (DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe from rubyinstaller.org) into C:\Ruby193\DevKit.
4. Added C:\Ruby193\DevKit\bin to my PATH.  (I opened Control Panel, System and Security, System, chose Advanced system settings to bring up the the "System Properties" window, advanced tab.  There I clicked the "Environment Variables" button to bring up another window.  In the "System Variables" section, I selected the "PATH" variable, clicked Edit, and appended ";C:\Ruby193\DevKit\bin".)
5. Closed all currently open command/dos windows and opened a new one (so that the new PATH would take effect).
6. In the command window, ran the following:

   6a. `gem install rails`

   6b. `gem install ruby-debug-ide19 --platform=ruby`    (This failed.)

   6c. `cd \Ruby193\Devkit`

   6d. `devkitvars.bat

   6e. `curl -OL http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem`

   6f. `curl -OL http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75415/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem`

   6g. `gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem`

   6h. `gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=c:\ruby193\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby-1.9.3-p327`

   6i. `gem install ruby-debug-ide19 --platform=ruby`  (Same as above, but this time it installed without error.)
7. Downloaded and installed an eval of RubyMine 4.5.4.  (Several people had said RubyMine will install necessary missing gems.)
8. In RubyMine:

   8a. Ruby didn't know where the SDK was, so I clicked File, Settings.  In the left pane of the settings window that appeared, I clicked "Ruby SDK and Gems".  In the right pane, I clicked "Add SDK..." and selected `C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe (ruby-1.9.3-p327)`.  Clicked OK to return to main window.

   8b. Clicked Run, Debug, which brought up a context menu.  Several items in the menu had numeric labels on their left.  Selected "Development:myproject" (which had the number "1." at its left).

   8c. A window popped up saying “The gem ruby-debug-base19x required by the debugger is not currently installed.  Install it?"  I chose yes. The text in the download progress window changed quickly, but it appeared to download at least 2 gems:

   - `ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre10.gem –no-rdoc`
   - `linecache____`   (I couldn't make out the blank part)

   8d. Tried debugging again.  I believe it was at this point that the console warned me about needing to have a correct version of "libmysql.dll" in the C:\Ruby193\bin folder.  I copied the file from the old Ruby installation which I had renamed to C:\Ruby193\bin in step 1 above.

   8e. Tried debugging once again. This time RubyMine said a "specified module could not be found:  `C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so`.  Browsing the C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib folder, I noticed that there was a "mysql" folder rather than a "mysql2" folder and that the "mysql" folder had a 1.9 folder with a mysql2.so file.  So, I created a "mysql2" folder and copy all of the contents from the "mysql" folder to the "mysql2" folder.

   8f. Tried debugging once again, and this time it worked.

   8g. Exited RubyMine.
9. Launched Aptana.  In Aptana:

   9a.  In the Project Explorer tab in the left pane, I selected the root of my project.

   9b.  In the menu bar, I clicked Run, then Debug Server.

It worked!  The console read:

`Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta14, ruby-debug-base 0.11) listens on 127.0.0.1:53561

    => Booting WEBrick

    => Rails 3.2.9 application starting in development on ht tp://0.0.0.0:3000

    => Call with -d to detach

    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server

    [2012-12-20 20:23:51] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1

    [2012-12-20 20:23:51] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-11-10) [i386-mingw32]

    [2012-12-20 20:23:51] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4416 port=3000`

In IE, when I browse `http://localhost:3000/`, it runs in the debugging context.  (URL misspelling is intentional so that this post passed stackoverflow's posting validation tests.)