# How to bind rvm with eclipse's settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rvm

I'm developing using multiple ruby instances and gemset for different apps. In order to switch between my ruby versions and gemsets, I use the .rvmrc file. I also use Eclipse with the radrails plugin as my development tool. Is there any way to get eclipse to switch automatically between the different gemsets and ruby version using rvm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Go into your project directory and create a file called .rvmrc containing the line:

rvm use ruby-1.8.7-p330@testing --default
(or whatever ruby version/gemset you like)

now do
cd ..
cd -
answer "y"
and now Eclipse should use the specified ruby version
(maybe you need to restart Eclipse first).
```

Comment: The reason why eclipse didn't seemed to see the .rvmrc file is that it needs to be in the same folder as the .project file, even tho in console it can be in a parent folder.