# Debugging Ruby 2.2 with Eclipse

Tags: ruby, eclipse, debugging, byebug

I'm trying to use step-through debugging in Ruby 2.2. I see that [byebug is the debugger of choice for Ruby 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083451/debugging-in-ruby-1-9), but Eclipse doesn't appear to recognise it. Steps to reproduce:

1. Do a fresh install of the [Windows 64bit distrib of Ruby 2.2.2](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) (I'm using Windows 8.1)
2. Install the Ruby 2.0 64bit DevKit - version 'DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe'
3. Add both Ruby and DevKit bin directories to PATH env variable
4. gem install byebug
5. Debug in Eclipse (Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1); Build id: 20140925-1800 & Dynamic Languages Toolkit - Ruby Development Tools  5.0.0.201306060709)

Result:

> Debugging Engine not started
>   The 'Fast Ruby Debugger (ruby-debug)' is selected, but the 'ruby-debug' or 'debugger' gems don't seem to be installed in the selected Ruby Interpreter (C:\Apps\Ruby22-x64\bin\ruby.exe)

I tried installing the debugger gem, but [it apparently doesn't support Ruby 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395453/gem-install-debugger-error). A response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452539/configuring-gems-in-eclipse) suggests byebug and Eclipse don't mix, but it wasn't part of the OP's question and isn't addressed by anyone else.

Anyone able to help? If I need to regress to an earlier version of Ruby, what version should I be using?

Answer (score 4):

- Ruby 2.2
- Rails 4
- No extra Gem

### 1. Choose "Ruby Built-In Debugger":

[image]

### 2. Add a Debug Configuration:

1. Input your command on "Lunch script"
2. "Debug".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the Ruby Built-In Debugger, on Eclipse go to Window > Preferences > Ruby > Engines and choose "Ruby Built-In Debugger" in the dropdown list.

Not sure if this works with Ruby 2.x, but for me is working with Ruby 1.9.3.