# Can't install ruby-debug, error: rb_method_entry_t.called_id

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-debug

I'm trying to install ruby-debug. I'm using Mac OS 10.7.4, XCode version 2308, and Ruby version 1.9.3-p194.

Following the instructions here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-ruby-debug, I tried running

```
sudo gem install ruby-debug
```

I got the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-ruby-dir
    --without-ruby-dir
    --with-ruby-include
    --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
    --with-ruby-lib
    --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
extconf.rb:16:in `block in <main>': break from proc-closure (LocalJumpError)
from /Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:18:in `call'
from /Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:18:in `create_makefile_with_core'
from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
```

So I tried the following command:

```
sudo gem install debugger
```

Which resulted in:

```
Fetching: columnize-0.3.6.gem (100%)
Fetching: debugger-ruby_core_source-1.1.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: debugger-linecache-1.1.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Fetching: debugger-1.1.4.gem (100%)
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed columnize-0.3.6
Successfully installed debugger-ruby_core_source-1.1.3
Successfully installed debugger-linecache-1.1.1
Successfully installed debugger-1.1.4
4 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for columnize-0.3.6...
Installing ri documentation for debugger-ruby_core_source-1.1.3...
Installing ri documentation for debugger-linecache-1.1.1...
Couldn't find file to include 'VERSION' from lib/linecache19.rb
Installing ri documentation for debugger-1.1.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for columnize-0.3.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for debugger-ruby_core_source-1.1.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for debugger-linecache-1.1.1...
Couldn't find file to include 'VERSION' from lib/linecache19.rb
Installing RDoc documentation for debugger-1.1.4...
```

So I researched the issue and finally came across this post:

[how do I install ruby-debug in ruby 1.9.3 / Rails 3.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122232/how-do-i-install-ruby-debug-in-ruby-1-9-3-rails-3-2-1)

Everything worked until I tried the command:

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=$SANDBOX/packages/ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

Which just reproduced the first error, above. So I looked into

```
rb_method_entry_t.called_id
```

And found this post: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/56/#issuecomment-3463264

I tried his suggested steps, except for rehash (which I'm not sure how to do with rvm, and didn't want to switch to rbenv just to try it). I downloaded all the gems he recommended to a folder, and ran the following command:

```
gem install *.gem -- --with-ruby-include=$(echo ~/.rvm/rubies/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p194/) --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

It installed linecache19-0.5.13 fine, but it choked on ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem, producing the first error again.

I also tried uninstalling the debugger gems added when I ran sudo gem install debugger, but that hasn't changed anything.

I'm at a loss for what to do next.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't use sudo when using rvm, though I don't think it's related to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ruby-debug is broken for ruby 1.9, give "pry" a try, instead. Maybe it is possible to get ruby-debug working but I wouldn't count on it.

[Debugging in ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083451/debugging-in-ruby-1-9?lq=1)

Comment: Yeah, I switched to pry a few weeks ago, and it works brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is rather old but I got the same error today and this the first result when I google the error.

For me debugger was installing as a dependency and running

```
gem install debugger
```

before bundle fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this with Ruby 2.0.0 installed via RVM.

RVM will just install with the binaries if they are available, which is faster, but debugger needs the source too

```
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --disable-binary
```