# Ruby debug ide with error ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-debug

I have too many errors when i want installing ruby-debug, and ruby-debug-ide.

Error like this (bundle install):

```
Using ruby_core_source (0.1.5) 
Using linecache19 (0.5.13) 
Using rails (3.2.5) 
Using ref (1.0.0) 
Installing ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.24) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:39: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... yes
checking for insns.inc... yes
checking for insns_info.inc... yes
checking for eval_intern.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling ruby_debug.c
ruby_debug.c:24:19: error: conflicting types for ‘rb_iseq_compile_with_option’
/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p125/vm_core.h:505:7: note: previous declaration of ‘rb_iseq_compile_with_option’ was here
ruby_debug.c: In function ‘context_jump’:
ruby_debug.c:2403:53: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
ruby_debug.c:2417:27: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
make: *** [ruby_debug.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.24 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.24/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.24), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ruby-debug-base19 -v '0.11.24'` succeeds before bundling.
```

On same solution:

```
gem install ruby-debug-base or ruby-debug-base19
```

same error,

```
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: This seems to be the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122232/how-do-i-install-ruby-debug-in-ruby-1-9-3-rails-3-2-1

Comment: Yes, i read this, but still doing this 
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: I heard ruby-debug19 is deprecated, you should use the debugger gem instead...

Comment: That sounds familiar, @citraL, but that probably won't help him with the `ruby-debug-ide` part.