# Testing Factory_Girl in Rails console leads to Stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, factory-bot

I try to put Factory_girl in my Rails apps for testing.

Here is part of the Gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', :group => [:development, :test]

group :development do
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1', :require => false
  gem 'populator', '1.0.0'
  gem 'ruby-debug19'
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 3.5.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'rb-inotify'
  gem 'libnotify'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require=>'sqlite3'
end
```

Then I go in the console to test the install of Factory_Girl by, `rails c`:
To call the `find_definitions` method for instance:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.5)
irb(main):002:0> FactoryGirl.find_definitions
NameError: uninitialized constant FactoryGirl
    from (irb):2
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in     `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in     `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top         (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

So I assume that I have to require the gem: I do so and:

```
irb(main):003:0> require 'factory_girl_rails'
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
Maybe IRB bug!!
```

I got this strange error.

What am I doing wrong?

For information, I'm on Rails 3.0.5 with ruby 1.9.2.

The gem config is:

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [i686-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86-linux
- GEM PATHS:
   - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
   - /home/izambard/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
 - GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :benchmark => false
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
```

Comment: Just by the way: You are using ruby-debug19 which does not work anymore. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10414984/773690

Comment: @iblue Ok thanks for the info, I'll update this point on my projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I had a require `factory_girl_rails` in the spec_helper.rb and in the factories.rb file. I remove the one in factories.rb and it is now working... :-s

Answer (score 2):

You are running the development environment while including FactoryGirl in your test environment. If you run a console in the test environment, FactoryGirl will get included.

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails c
```

I am not quite sure why `require 'factory_girl_rails'` in development leads to an infinite recursion. May be a bug in factory girl or an old rails version.

Comment: I was also thinking of a version issue. Nevertheless, I see that factory_girl 3.5.0 has runtime dependencies with activesupport >=3.0.0. And I use Rails 3.0.5 (activesupport = 3.0.5). So normally It should work. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Actually, when I use `rails c test`, I directly get the stack level too deep and the console stop.