# Can't install ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25) on windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using python 3.2.3 and ruby 1.9.3-p194 installed using rubyinstaller.
When I try to execute this command as shown in a tutorial (coursera Saas class) I have this error that I can't resolve (I'm new to ruby)

```
D:\Work\repository\hw2_rottenpotatoes>bundle install --without production
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using multi_json (1.0.4)
Using activesupport (3.1.0)
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using i18n (0.6.0)
Using activemodel (3.1.0)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.3.5)
Using rack-cache (1.0.3)
Using rack-mount (0.8.3)
Using rack-test (0.6.1)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.0.3)
Using actionpack (3.1.0)
Using mime-types (1.17.2)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.3.0)
Using actionmailer (3.1.0)
Using arel (2.2.1)
Using tzinfo (0.3.31)
Using activerecord (3.1.0)
Using activeresource (3.1.0)
Using archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
Using bundler (1.2.0.rc)
Using coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
Using execjs (1.2.13)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Using json (1.6.3)
Using rdoc (3.12)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.1.0)
Using coffee-rails (3.1.1)
Using columnize (0.3.5)
Using haml (3.1.4)
Using jquery-rails (1.0.19)
Using libv8 (3.3.10.4)
Using ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
Using linecache19 (0.5.12)
Using rails (3.1.0)
Installing ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:39: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecate
fig.
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... yes
checking for insns.inc... yes
checking for insns_info.inc... yes
checking for eval_intern.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
generating ruby_debug-i386-mingw32.def
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling ruby_debug.c
ruby_debug.c:29:19: error: conflicting types for 'rb_iseq_compile_with_option'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p125/vm_core.h:505:7: note: previous declaration of 'rb_iseq_compile_with_option' was here
ruby_debug.c: In function 'context_jump':
ruby_debug.c:2414:53: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
ruby_debug.c:2428:27: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
make: *** [ruby_debug.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ruby-debug-base19 -v '0.11.25'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Thnx

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083451/debugging-in-ruby-1-9/10414984#10414984

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your `C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out` file