# Failed To Build gem native extension for debugging

Tags: ruby

I am installing debugger for Ruby version 1.9.3-p448 then followed the following steps to get debugger installed but on step five I get the error.

The steps are

1) Download Ruby development Kit from the following link and extract it in Ruby base directory: In my case it was C:Ruby193

2) Open a windows command prompt and change the directory to the DevKit folder.  Type following command:

```
ruby dk.rb init
```

3) Now run the following command to enable DevKit for the Ruby installations in your machine.

```
ruby dk.rb install
```

4) Run following command

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide --platform=ruby --pre
```

5) For ruby-debug file

First download linecache19-0.5.13.gem and ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=8883,
then execute following commands.

```
gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem 

gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include= C:\Ruby193\ruby-1.9.3-p448-src
```

6) Type following commands

```
irb
 require 'ruby-debug'
```

But 2nd command in step 5 is not getting through and failed to get me proceeded.

Help me in find what i am missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083451/debugging-in-ruby-1-9/2826202#2826202

Comment: What are the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach now is to use the [new debugger gem](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) if you need a help to start with the new gem you can see Ryan Bates [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-ruby-revised).

In your Gemfile put:

```
gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

You can then add a breakpoint anywhere in your code using the debugger keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It's some time since the question was posted but it may be useful to somebody.

I was facing a similar problem in Mac OS X with the same version (1.9.3-p448),
I followed the same steps and had to make GCC visible in my path.

1. In windows you can install MinGW:

   http://www.mingw.org/
   http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW
2. Add the compiler in your path, if you installed in C:\

   you must include C:\MinGW\bin in your PATH as explained in the link below.

   http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started
3. Install the linecache gem

   ```
    gem install linecache -v 1.2.0 --with-ruby-include= C:\Ruby193\ruby-1.9.3-p448-src
   ```
4. Install the debugger gem

   ```
    gem install debugger -v 1.6.5 --with-ruby-include= C:\Ruby193\ruby-1.9.3-p448-src
   ```

It should work