# How to debug using rails console and puts in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I want to get some lines printed in irb opened through rails console. I have seen a lot of SO questions of how to achieve it. But I get nothing in the irb.

below is the code--

```
def show
puts 'in show method'
@post = Feed.find_by_id params[:id]
puts @post.inspect
redirect_to root_path unless @post.present? 
end
```

now I have opened server by command `rails server`. Also, In another terminal I gave the command `rails console`, it opened the irb prompt. when in browser I run `localhost:3000/posts/82` it gives the correct post, but nothing is shown in the console. What step am I missing? I want to print something in the console when a particular method is called.

Comment: You want to use `debugger` or `byebug`. Rails console gives you an access to your app, but not to examining requests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Best way to debug is to use the `debugger` command.

If you are using ruby 2.0 or above, you have to use the `gem 'byebug'` and if you are using 1.9 or below, then `gem ruby-debug`

then, when you run your server in development mode, your server will stop when it reaches the `debugger` allowing you to see your objects' state and modify them (much better than simply using `puts`

The program will stop in the same window that your server runs.

Some basic commands:

- <kbd>c</kbd> continues the execution until next debugger is found
- <kbd>n</kbd> runs the next command. If it is a function executes the
  function
- <kbd>s</kbd> step into the next command. If it is a
  function, you will get into the function and see the variables
- <kbd>display expression</kbd> on every step display the result of the
  expression you write (very useful when debugging loops)
- <kbd>undisplay expression_number</kbd> stops displaying the expresion
- <kbd>display</kbd> shows all the expressions being displayed
- <kbd>list</kbd> Displays the source code being executed
- <kbd>help</kbd> shows the available commands   <kbd>help
  command_name</kbd> shows detailed info about a command

More info about debugging: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: Hi, there, I had took that approach, but though the debugger installed, writing rails server --debugger asked me to install ruby-debug, I tried installing that and it gave me some error, following some SO posts, I instead installed ruby-debug19 and continued by the command `rails server --debugger` to give me the same error

Comment: Theoretically you don't need to start the server with `--debugger` it should take it automatically. Be sure that your `gem 'ruby-debug19'` is in your development group in the gemfile.

Comment: There's another SO question related with debugging in ruby 1.9 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083451/debugging-in-ruby-1-9 take a look to the second answer (it is suggested to use gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test] instead of ruby-debug19 as it is not longer maintained)

Comment: Hey thanks, it works now, I was trying to install it using `sudo gem install debugger` instead of putting it in the gem file and doing `sudo bundle install`, since I thought it won't make any difference. Could that be the reason?

Comment: yes, that could be a reason. And I recommend you to run bundle install without sudo... that might be a source of problems too

Comment: Gotcha! Please also assist me in viewing the contents of puts, if I don't use debugger

Comment: You still can use the debugger (if you are in a loop you can write something like <% debugger if condition %>. As well you can use the `debug` helper to print things in a nicer format ( <%= debug [:a, :b, :c] %>)

Comment: Can the debugger be used along with feedly_api running as a cron job? The debugger is not launching this way

Answer (score 2):

The `puts 'in show method'` in `line 2` won't show the output in `rails console`. Instead it shows the output in the same terminal where you did `rails server`. They might be lost with so much of output, so try to find it there itself.

Comment: Yeah, it seem to get lost there, Can you give some suggestion on how can I see that since I am new to ubuntu.

Comment: Try using a different logger, may be awesome print. In your Gemfile, add the following `gem 'awesome_print'` and then instead of puts, you can do `ap 'in show method'`. It will show you colored output.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `Rails.logger.debug "in show method"` etc.
2. In the second tab in terminal tail log/development.log like this

   ```
   $ cd rails_app_root
   $ tail -f log/development.log
   ```

   or

   ```
   $ cd rails_app_root
   $ less +F log/development.log
   ```

There you will find all the output from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Rails.logger

> Rails.logger.info "Some debugging info I want to see in my
>   development log.------#{@post.inspect}"

It will print @post value in log file.

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of `puts` debugging. e.g;

```
def index
  method = Kernel.instance_method(:method)
  p method.bind(request).call(:headers).source_location
  @users = User.all
end
```

The above snippet helps you find where the method is implemented:

```
Processing by UsersController#index as */*
["/Users/aaron/git/rails/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb", 201]
```

You can find more cool `puts` debugging [here](https://tenderlovemaking.com/2016/02/05/i-am-a-puts-debuggerer.html).